# .Net Core web application running STA thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, sta

I would like to run GET method in controller in STA mode.
For Web API this worked perfectly:
http://ryanhaugh.com/archive/2014/05/24/supporting-sta-threads-in-web-api/
Can it be translated to .NET Core?

Comment: Try it and see.  Bare in mind that code isn't really playing `async` nice with its `.Result` in `() => base.InvokeActionAsync(context, cancellationToken).Result`.  That will make at least some aspect of it synchonous

Comment: Why do you even want this? I cannot see a better way to kill performance

Comment: I have old application written in COM and I would like to allow users to use it via GET / POST requests.

Comment: Create a Windows Service, communicate it with the ASP.NET Core app with WCF or SignalR and done. Don't kill the server unnecessarily

Comment: @MickyD Yeah, of course, those were just samples. You can use WCF with named pipes anyway

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This is true :)

Answer (score 3):

I do it the same way now, except I create my thread differently.

```
Example example = new Example();
Thread thread =  = new Thread(
        delegate () //Use a delegate here instead of a new ThreadStart
        {
              example.StaRequired(); //Whatever you want to call with STA
        }
)
{
    IsBackground = false,
    Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
};
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start(); //Start the thread
thread.Join(); //Block the calling thread
```

The `IsBackground` and `Priority` part is optional of course.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

To use STA I created new thread:

```
ComClass c = new ComClass();
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => 
{
    c.StaRequired();
}));
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

Comment: Web apps generally should not be in the business of spinning up explicit threads that web servers aren't aware of.

Comment: I moved the thread start to ComClass as a new method. Does it make any sense?